# cohomological dimension for coarser/finer topologies

Tags: cohomology, cohomological-dimension, ag.algebraic-geometry, ct.category-theory

Given a sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ with respect to some Grothendieck topology, is the cohomological dimension for this sheaf less than or equal to the cohomological dimension of a finer topology?

Example: $cd_{Zar} \leq cd_{Nis} \leq cd_{ét}$.

Comment: There's a tag for just this sort of question, so I added it

Comment: I added ArXiv subject tags.  I hope you don't mind.

Comment: It seems to me you can take some reasonable topological space  and consider on it the coarser trivial topology  (only open sets are empty and whole space) and the finer discrete topology. Then the cohomology of the constant sheaf is strictly bigger in the middle topology, no?

Comment: @Minhyong: A sheaf for the discrete topology will rarely restrict to give a constant sheaf in the middle topology.

Comment: Tom: I think our interpretations of the question were different. If $X$ is a finer topology than $Y$, then we have a continuous map $f:X\rightarrow Y$. For any sheaf $F$ on $Y$, we can then consider the sheaf pull-back $f^*F$ obtained by sheafifying the presheaf pullback. I thought the question concerned the comparison between the cohomology of $F$ and that of $f^*F$. At least, this is the 'standard' comparison that comes up in practice. It seems to me that the constant sheaf always pulls back to the constant sheaf.

Comment: Of course, if $G$ is a sheaf on $X$, then the comparison between $G$ and $f_*(G)$, which is what you were doing, is also important.

Comment: Tom: I'm also quite puzzled by your remark on $Spec(\mathbb{R})$. In this case, are you considering $f_*$ or $f^*$? The first one will clearly preserve global sections, while the second one seems to take any sheaf on $Spec(\mathbb{R})_{Zar}$ to the set with trivial $Z/2$ action, and hence, also preserve $H^0$. Am I completely confused?

Comment: I have deleted my $Spec(\mathbb R)$ comment, which was in fact confused under any interpetation.


Comment: I was interpreting the question in the following literal way: Suppose we have one category with two Grothendieck topologies, one finer than the other. Suppose some presheaf is a sheaf with respect to both of them. If $H^n=0$ for all $n>d$ in the finer case, must the same be true in the other case?

Comment: But probably what was meant was: Take any presheaf and compare cohomological dim of the one associated sheaf and the other associated sheaf.

Comment: One thing I am definitely confused about is: If you have two topologies on one point set, (how) does that give you two Grothendieck topologies on one category?

Comment: "Suppose we have one category with two Grothendieck topologies, one finer than the other. Suppose some presheaf is a sheaf with respect to both of them. If Hn=0 for all n>d in the finer case, must the same be true in the other case?"

Yes, that is what i meant.

Comment: Without thinking it through too thoroughly, it seems to me that you are then considering $f_*$. Now, I'm not sure two different Grothendieck topologies on the same category is the best way to think about this issue. For example,  the Zariski and etale topologies are not normally defined on the same category. However, one can obviously enlarge the smaller one. That is, take the category of etale open sets, but then open covers are just the Zariski ones for each object. This shouldn't change anything significant.

Comment: Now, when you are refining a usual topological space $Y$ and want to think about one category, you can do likewise. So if $X$ is the same space with the discrete topology, think of $Y$ also as the category of all subsets of $Y$, but with the induced topology on each object. Cohomology of sheaves on $Y$ should remain unaffected by this process.